# php concatenating string math operation

Tags: php, concatenation

```
$a =  'hello' . 3 + 6 + 10;
echo $a; // 16
```

I would expect it to be hello19 not 16.

I know I can put the math operation in ():

```
$a =  'hello' . (3 + 6 + 10);
echo $a; // hello19
```

But why is php returning 16?

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 2):

In PHP both `.` and `+` have equal [precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php) and are both left associative.

As a result

```
'hello' . 3 + 6 + 10;
```

is evaluated as

```
('hello' . 3) + 6 + 10;

= 'hello3' + 6 + 10                           

= ('hello3' + 6) + 10 // String 'hello3' when interpreted as a number gives 0
                      // as it starts with a non-digit.

= 6 + 10

= 16
```

Answer (score 0):

It's happening because '`hello' . 3` is avaluated as 0 when followed with math + operation.

when using brackets the sum is evaluated first and then the number is converted to string and concatenated with `'hello'`

Answer (score 0):

first look at this:

```
$a =  'hello' . 3;
echo (int)$a; //echoes 0
```

that's because `hello3` starts with a letter but not a digit and php casts it to integer as zero. so `0+6+10` is obvious 16.

the second code *first* computes `3 + 6 + 10` in braces and then conctenates `hello` with the result which is 19

Answer (score 0):

Following PHP's operator [precedence and associativity](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php) you can rewrite your expression to an equivalent expression as follows:

```
'hello' . 3 + 6 + 10;        <==>
('hello' . 3) + 6 + 10;      <==>
((('hello' . 3) + 6) + 10);
```

And if we evaluate that expression, as PHP would:

```
((('hello' . 3) + 6) + 10);  =
(('hello3' + 6) + 10);       =
((0 + 6) + 10));             =
(6 + 10);                    =
16
```